# Unable to Find MIN value from a excel Column(pre populated with formula )

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to Extract MIN value from a excel column which has been pre-populated using formulas(in my case i have used a Substitute formula ).

The Result I am getting is '0' instead of the min value in the column. Any help will be appreciated.

I Have attached the screenshots below:-

[image]

[image]

Comment: The data array you use as a source contains string data type values which are ignored by MIN(). Replace your formula with `=0+SUBSTITUTE(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer @Akina . It worked for me .